# How to pass OpenGL Shader 'sampler2d' in GPUImage?

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es, gpuimage

I am writing a custom shader and I want to pass & change sampler2d property in OpenGL Shader in GPUImage at run time.

```
    varying highp vec2 centerLocation;
    varying highp float pointSpacing;

    uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;

    void main()
    {
    mediump vec4 fragmentColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, gl_PointCoord);
      gl_FragColor = fragmentColor;
    }
```

Comment: someone ask this quesiton before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48296781/gpuimage2-passing-gl-texture-to-shader